# Creating dust deflated by wind

Tags: modeling, particles, volumetrics, effects

I want to create spaceship landing scene where it's engines produces a lot of dust while the ship is descending to the ground. How can I achieve that crazy chaotic dust effect? [image: Dust]

Comment: Did you try something by now?

Comment: Tried smoke simulation with wind force field, but I get some bad effect which is more smoke than dust. Maybe there is a specific way of refining that method. But I also would like to know other options.

Comment: Could you add some sample video/animation of desired effect?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wtNdK5gBqwE Desired effect. I also want it physically matching the flow from the engine.

Comment: Any ideas what is his node setup ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60401/discussion-between-nikita-demidenko-and-luked).