# How to I create swirls of dust?

Tags: particles

I made this using other software: 
https://youtu.be/yS1SEQP11o0

I want the dust to look like it was blown by the propellers as it swirls in the turbulence to eventually settle.

There is this exact question that ended up in the chat rooms but that doesn't help me any.

[Creating dust deflated by wind](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81316/creating-dust-deflated-by-wind)

Comment: I've made example there, but the link changed: https://imgur.com/1a91s05 It's kinda long answer, more like a tutorial. If you are familiar with basic animation and smoke simulation I can make an overview for this method but certainly not step-by-step guide as this will be an overkill.

Comment: @LukeD All I see on imagur is 1 video that last 10 second of an animation of smoke and nothing else.

Answer (score -2):

In this tutorial you will see exactly what is needed to learn do to to get something similar as described.

https://youtu.be/k8lHVnQdtSA

Comment: to make this answer more useful please make a rough description of the contents of the suggested link, so that the answer stands on its onwn. If the link changes or disappears then this answer will make no sense.